Correlation of two sets growing to the same value but different number of samples
How do I get the correlation between two sets with different lengths? I know Pearson correlation won't work. But can I do something about it if they grow to the same value. Here's what I mean.
Say, I have two sets:
[1, 2, 3, 4] and [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
We can see that they are different lengths, but they have the same sum.
[1, 3, 6, 10] and [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 10]
We can see they both accumulate to 10.
I am thinking, if I graph them like the cumulative sum on the x axis and the original points on y axis. I can like "connect the dots". After that, then I am thinking maybe I can convolve them or something or like their inner product? Not really sure what I'm talking about.
Does this somehow work? Can you suggest some methods that can help with this problem.
Thank you very much!
EDIT:
In response to the question of what this data represents, this problem is a signal processing problem.
The system works like this. I receive a random number of spikes in a period. In the case of my example above, say 10 seconds.
Every 10 seconds, I read some spikes, but the time arrival of spike from the previous one is varied. That is what is represented by this set:
[1, 2, 3, 4] and [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
Now the question is, how related are these two?
EDIT 2:
What is "related" in this context?
For my application, the idea of "related"-ness looks something like this:
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
is slightly related to
[4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
If I graph the curve of the arrival times, one is somewhat just a delayed version of the other.
I don't know what to call this property I am trying to describe. Hope this description helps!
EDIT 3:
Given this: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
We can also say it's related to:
[3.9, 3.1, 2, 0.8, 1.2, 2, 2]
Also I need to be able to tell if the sampling is late or early.
We can say
[3.9, 3.1, 1.9, 0.8, 1.2, 2, 2]
is late compared to the given.
And
[2.5, 5, 4, 3, 0.5]
is early compared to the given.
EDIT 4:
Sorry this got confusing.
What is late and what is early?
Given A = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
B = [4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
and C = [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
B is late compared to A.
C is early compared to A.
The intuition is this.

   [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> A: perfect timing
      [4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2] -> B: late timing
[1, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> C: early timing

See that some parts of the B resemble A, and C likewise resembles A. They have resemblances but the indexes are shifted.
B and C are "related" to A.
In addition, we can say that
D = [3.9, 3.1, 2, 0.8, 1.2, 2, 2]
D is a slightly inaccurate version of B.
In my context of "related"-ness, D is also related to A.
Hope that helps!
EDIT 5:
More clarification on "early" and "late"
Here's a MATLAB code and its result. Notice how the part of the graph of C resembling A is to the right of A. Here's the sense of "early" I am saying. The same part in B is to the left of A. Here's the sense of "late." Like imagine signals in the time domain. If a signal is early, it's to the right of the reference. If it's late, it's to the left of the reference.
A = [5 4 3 2 1];
B = [4 3 2 1 1 2 2];
C = [1 5 4 3 2];
D = [3.9 3.1 2 0.8 1.2 2, 2];

cuA = cumsum(A);
cuB = cumsum(B);
cuC = cumsum(C);
cuD = cumsum(D);

figure;
plot(cuA, A, 'y');
hold on;
plot(cuB, B, 'r');
plot(cuC, C, 'b');
plot(cuD, D, 'g');

legend("A", "B", "C", "D");



Correlation is a pairwise operation which requires information about two (or more) values at the same point. If this is not the case correlation does not make sense. What does this data represent and why do you want to correlate it? What is your research question?

I edited the question!

You need to tell us how you conceive of "related," because your data suggest several different forms of relationship.  For instance, if arrival times in both processes are close to uniform but the average spike rate per unit time differs between those processes, are they "related"?  If the waiting times in the processes have different distributions but have the same average, are they "related"?  If an arrival in one process can be used to predict near-future arrivals in the other process, are they "related"? In short, what specific property of these processes are you focusing on?

@whuber I edited the question!

Examples are always good.  But here they are a little puzzling, because it's not apparent how you conceive of them as being related.  Could you state specifically what you are evaluating when you see "one is a delayed version of the other," especially in light of the fact one might have more spikes than the other?

Hello @whuber Thanks for the patience. I edited the question. Hope that sheds some more light!

I can see how C is early relative to A, but by the same criterion B looks systematically earlier than A, too: the first five arrival times in B are all equal to or shorter than those in A, looking like an accelerated version of A.  In what sense, then, do you contend "B is late compared to A"?

It sounds like you have a continuous-time point process that you examine every 10 seconds. Your values seem to be the time of each event relative to the previous event. If that's the case, it's not clear how you deal with the restrictions placed by the binning into 10-second intervals: is the first value in a set the time since the beginning of that time interval, or the time since an event that might have happened in a prior time interval? Also, it seems that [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] might be turned into [4, 3, 2, 1, 5] simply by moving the time origins of the bins.

I suspect that there's some underlying question that you're trying to answer and have come up with "correlation" or "relatedness" as a way to answer that question. If you edit the question to specify more clearly what you are recording, why/how you are binning the data, what the values mean (as asked in my prior comment), and the actual question that you're trying to answer, you might get help with a better and more reliable way to proceed.
